# Display changes of webView from function

Tags: objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, webview

In My project i display an `viewController` from class

```
settings.m
```

in that `viewController` after an touch button event called,i calling to local function that display `webView` with animation after loading java script like this:

```
 [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; 
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"settingsAnimate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 120, 320, 320)]; 
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:self.webView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

its working...

but now i want to call if when event happens in other class,so I created an function with that code below in settings.m  and after my event happens i calling to that function from that class:

```
settings *ss = [settings alloc];
[ss showAnimation];
```

I get in into that function in `settings.m` but nothing happens...what could be the problem?

Tryied using delegate: in my `Options.m`, its comming into the function but the webView dont chage.

```
@protocol IGameP
- (void) showAnimation;
@end

@interface options : CDVPlugin<IGameP>{
    id <IGameP> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <IGameP> delegate;
```

in

```
options.m:

settings *s1t = [settings alloc];
[self setDelegate: s1t];

[self.delegate showAnimation];
```

Comment: Why don't you use `settings *ss = [[settings alloc] init];`?

Comment: Well that's not the point; you need to always call `init` when creating an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**delegate**](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) for backward messaging (ie calling function in other classes). As such u want to take effect of your requirement in a view from another view best is to use **delegate**

Comment: Does it matter? i'm getting into that function...i use: `settings *mySet = [settings alloc]; [mySet: showAnimationFunc];`

Comment: but here memory reference of settings is new and it will not take effect

Comment: any idea why when i check `if (self.delegate)` before sending message it always nil? where should i initialize it? followed the link in your answer

Comment: download sample check how delegate works? So no need to alloc delegate plus just import your another viewcontroller  in viewcontroller and add delegates @interface viewcontroller : UIViewController  <anotherVCDelegateName> and add description of method in viewcontroller.m file